# CELG Covered calls with BMY Acquisition

Tags: covered-call

I have 700 shares of CELG but have written January 2021 100 strike calls against my shares for 5-6$.  If CELG closes the acquisition below 100$, would I receive the premium I sold the covered calls at or would I get some new covered call position in the BMY shares I receive?  My thought is if they are out of the money they should be worthless.

Recall, the BMY offer is 1 share of BMY plus 50$ cash.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You sold the call so the premium is your, no matter what happens.

If your short call is assigned, you'll sell the stock for $100 and you'll be done with it.  This is highly unlikely since CELG is $98, the strike is $100 and the expiration is 16 months away.

Based on the merger  terms you provided, you will receive one share of BMY and $50 for each CELG share that you own.  The CELG options will be adjusted to reflect these terms.  If assigned, you will be required to deliver 100 shares of BMY and $50 cash.  If you are not assigned, you'll own the BMY shares and you'll get to keep the $50.

Here's a coincidence for you.  In 2008, Celgene acquired Pharmion.  The terms of the deal were:

- Each share of PHRM was converted into the right to receive 0.8367 of a share of CELG common stock, plus $25.00 cash. Cash-in-lieu was provided for  fractional CELG shares.

On the date of the merger, all outstanding options were adjusted as follows to requires the receipt or delivery of:

- 83 shares of CELG Common Stock plus $2,536.81 cash ($2,500.00+ $36.81 cash in lieu of 0.67 fractional share of CELG Common Stock (based on a whole-share price of $54.94 for fractional CELG shares)

You can see how the existing PHRM options were adjusted to reflect the acquisition.

Comment: Did you happen to mean 50 shares of BMY and 50$ cash?  I don't see why I would have to deliver 100 shares of BMY.

Comment: My answer was based on your statement that the merger is for 1 share of BMY and $50 cash. A Google search indicates that "Celgene shareholders will receive 1.0 Bristol-Myers share and $50 in cash for each share of Celgene. They will also receive one tradeable Contingent Value Right for each share owned, which will entitle them to a payment for the achievement of certain future regulatory milestones."

Comment: ok I think I finally get it.  My brokerage would probably hold the 50$ in cash in a reserve account so I can't take it and use it on something else.  Because I would in essence have 700 BMY with -7 contracts against those shares at the 50$ strike but those contracts also require the 50$ cash to close.  is that about right?

Comment: The OCC has a variety of ways to adjust option contracts.  In this case, I think that the strike will remain at $100 and delivery will include 100 shares, $5k, a small amount of cash-in-lieu and the CVR (whatever its terms are).  Whether you can utilize the $35k in cash for something else will depend on whether it's a cash account or not.  If yes, they'll restrict you from using the $35k of cash.  If it's a margin account the a different story. In general, people should be very careful with adjusted options because they can be very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've *already* received the premium. The question is whether your options will get exercised or not.  If they are exercised before the merger then they will work just like a regular option - if CELG is above the strike the options will be exercised and you'll sell your shares for $100. Otherwise the options will expire worthless.

If there is a merger, then you'll receive BMY shares and $50 cash for each share of CELG you own. You'll also receive new, equivalent replacement options on BMY plus $50 with a $100 strike. If BMY is above $50 at expiry, then you'll sell your BMY shares *plus* the $50 for $100 (how this actually settles I do not know - you may just give up the shares and keep the net $50). If BMY is below $50, you'll keep your shares and the $50.

Effectively you'll receive shares of BMY, $50 per share of CELG you owned, and a new short call option on BMY with a $50 strike.

Comment: Ok I think that's what I was afraid of having happen.  I thought I was selling something that gave me some free "time premium" on CELG only.  But, it seems more complicated now that I would have a BMY covered call for 2021 and have to wait to see if it closes above 50$.  I guess I have to decided if I want to mess around with all of this or just close the option position now.

Comment: The current CELG options will continue to exist but they will be adjusted, requiring the receipt or delivery of 100 shares of BMY and $50.  If assigned, he gives up both.  If not assigned, he keeps both (the $50 is cost basis not profit).  He will not give up the shares and keep the $50.